# Interrupt with name identifier [Sigaction - Linux]

Tags: c, linux

Is there any possibility to give a certain interrupt an ID? To be more precise, I have two serial inputs that triggers an interrupt, which in turn calls the same function. However, how do I know which serial issued the interrupt?

I'm using "sigaction" to modify the signals generated by the serial input.

I may either use:

```
void     (*sa_handler)(int);
```

or

```
void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
```

The first option is going to be excluded because it only specifies the signal, which can be any valid signal except SIGKILL and SIGSTOP. In my case it's signal 29.

Thus I'm looking more into the second option.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct sigaction saio;

    // Open port
    fileDescriptor1 = open(devicePath1, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)
    fileDescriptor2 = open(devicePath2, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)

    sigemptyset(&saio[deviceId].sa_mask);
    saio[deviceId].sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    saio[deviceId].sa_restorer = NULL;
    saio[deviceId].sa_sigaction = signal_handler_IO;
    sigaction(SIGIO,&saio[deviceId],NULL);

    fcntl(fileDescriptor1, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    fcntl(fileDescriptor1, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    fcntl(fileDescriptor1, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC );

    fcntl(fileDescriptor2, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    fcntl(fileDescriptor2, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    fcntl(fileDescriptor2, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC );

    while(1);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void signal_handler_IO (int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr)
{
    printf("Interrupt occured!\n");
}
```

I found something similar to what I'd like to do. However, in that case the person is applying a timer interrupt. [Timer interrupt with IDs](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-solve-this-multiple-linux-timer-with-single-signal-handler-4175496392/)

Sigaction page: [enter link description here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction)

I hope that enough information is provided for u being able to assist me. Cheers!

Edit:
Maybe I can retrieve the file descriptor? But a specified Id would be much handier.

Comment: A `signal` is not an `interrupt`.

Comment: Do you *need* to use signal-based notifications? Why not just `select` or `poll` for when the fd is readable/writable/exceptional?

Comment: @EOF My bad. First time I work with signals. The reason I made that statement was because when a certain signal occured, it does generate an interrupt. Right? Suggestion on better name? Thanks

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Hi, I'd rather use interrupts to handle signal events such as input from serial port. The reason is because the input will be stored in a buffer. I want the interrupt to handle the reading by itself. The code above is just a dummy code. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend a look at `fcntl()`, particularly `F_SETSIG`.

Comment: But the signal handler is not an interrupt handler, as EOF mentioned. The kernel handles the interrupt, and then marks your task as signalled. Then when it finishes the ISR, your application is scheduled for execution, but at the signal handler entry point. Because of that, I see no reason not to use select. Otherwise, what does your main thread do? Spin?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Oh really, so that's how it works. lol. I will follow your recommendation and go for "select()" instead. Thanks :)

Comment: More or less. I'm not really familiar with that part of the Linux kernel, but it should be pretty close.  I'm not insisting that you use `select`, but I'm not sure at this point why you wouldn't. A good counter argument (from someone with more experience with `SIGIO` than me) might convince me otherwise though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

info->si_fd should have the relevant file descriptor from within the context of your signal handler. (Reference: man sigaction)

EDIT: Evidently, you must also explicitly call

```
fcntl(fileDesciptor1, F_SETSIG, SIGIO);
```

This causes SIGIO to be emitted with valid info data (including `si_fd`), which apparently it doesn't normally do. From `man fcntl`:

> By  using  F_SETSIG with a nonzero value, and setting SA_SIGINFO
>   for the signal handler  (see  sigaction(2)),  extra  information
>   about  I/O events is passed to the handler in a siginfo_t struc‐
>   ture.

I don't believe it's possible to get an arbitrary pointer passed into the signal handler with SIGIO (or with most signals, for that matter.)

Beware that in some cases, signals may be coalesced (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181433/can-signal-be-ignored-lost). It's a good idea to check everything directly before going back to sleep in your mainloop.

select() or poll() are generally better options, as some of the comments suggest.

Comment: Reading the file descriptor inside the signal handler function, gives a '0'. Do you know why? I will take a closer look at "select()" aswell.

Comment: See my edits :) Also you should *really* avoid burning like that (while(1); is *very bad* practice in software), and printf() is not async-signal-safe (should not be invoked from signal handlers).

Comment: Why is that bad? :P In the end the program should always be running. I can't use the argument "F_SETSIG" because within fcntl.h it is defined within "ifdef __USE_GNU" .. lol

Comment: If you're unwilling to use F_SETSIG, then I don't think you have any further options available. You can define __USE_GNU or just manually write in its value of 10...

Comment: Re: "Why is that bad?" CPU time is a shared resource on a computer. When you burn like that, other processes that need CPU time (including processes that manage hard disks, and anything else you may have running) need to fight harder to get that time. You also prevent the CPU from going into a lower power state -  you're maximizing CPU power consumption. Go to `sleep` (or `poll`, or `select`, or `pause`, ...) when you don't need the CPU.

Comment: Worked! Haha why didn't I think of writing 10 manually lol .. Thanks @lyngvi. Edit: Well I see, thanks for the feedback! Im new to these kind of operating systems. Used to simple MCUs :P

Comment: :) No problem. Mind that it's not terribly portable (though you'll find most signal handling code is not as portable as it looks), but for working on Linux this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle serial I/O then you need kernel programming.there is OS doesn't work.